# How to change two endpoints in single test suite using Groovy?

Tags: groovy

Using setup script as

```
def result = com.eviware.soapui.support.UISupport.prompt("Please select the enviornment", "Environment", ['UAT1','UAT2','UAT3'])
def testcases = testSuite.getTestCaseList()
if(result == 'UAT1'){
   testcases.each { testcase ->
     def teststeps = testcase.getTestStepList() 
     teststeps.each { teststep ->
       teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint','')
     }
  }
```

to run the test suite for single endpoint.

However I am stuck in one scenario where testcase1 used "endpoint1" and testcase2 used"endpoint2" as endpoints. so wanted to know how we use switch case in this scenario to run both test cases with single click using Groovy in setup script?

Comment: you can store endpoint in an array and use setPropertyValue to set for each case  teststep.setPropertyValue('endpoint',endpoint[0]) like this. thanks for UISupport.prompt i saw it first time